# Flying with a baby, changing diapers onboard

Tags: air-travel, children, hygiene

Babies do require a nappy change more frequently when they are few weeks old, I am wondering is it a problem to change the diapers onboard? Do I have to worry about health issues when using lavatories? are lavatories equipped to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing on diapers on a plane is not a problem. Doing with no consideration for other passengers is a problem.

I can't speak for the quality of every airlines lavatories, but the feces from the baby **probably** present a greater health risk to others then whatever germs may be in the lavatory present to the baby. I'd recommend standard hygienic protocol (lots of wipes) and, if you're worried about the baby getting something in the lavatory, even wiping things down beforehand, .

Most airplane lavatories are equipped to handle this.

**Do**

- Change the baby in the bathroom. There's a fold down changing table.
- Dispose of the diaper promptly. Ask the flight attendants what to do 
  with the soiled diaper.
- Try sit on an aisle seat if you anticipate having to move  about
  frequently.

**Don't**

- Change the baby on the tray table or on the seat.
- Store the soiled diaper in the seat back.
- Leave a poopy mess in the lavatory.

See also: Number 5 on this [CNN list](http://www.cnn.com/2013/12/01/travel/reader-picks-plane-annoying/).

Comment: Also, bring diaper bags with you. They should sell them in baby supply stores. They are designed to hold soiled diapers and their associated odor.

Comment: And: Bring in lots of diapers. Think of the number you take for a trip by car of the same length. Add one extra diaper. Add another extra diaper, just in case. Now double the figure.